# How to identify an event after the other in Elm

Tags: elm

I have a `div` with the following action to mimic a menu

```
div
  [ onClick address Toggle
  , onFocus address Open
  , onBlur address Close
  ]
  [ ... some items with click handlers ]
```

When one tabs to the `div`, it has focus and executes `Open` which shows the menu.

When it loses focus, `onBlur` is raised and executes `Close` which hides the menu

When clicked, it toggles between `Open` or `Close`.

This works fine but there are a few issues

**Scenario**

1. When the user clicks on the `div`, it fires `onFocus` that opens the menu.
2. It then fires `onClick`, which executes toggle and thus closes the menu.

How do I identify an `onClick` after `onFocus` so as not to toggle the menu? If not, what is the best way to handle this scenario in Elm.

This works fine if the user tabs to the div and then clicks on it. Since it already has focus, it toggles and behaves as expected.

Comment: you should probably add some state for your model, so that you could keep trask if the menu is open or closed, and react to the events also accordingly to the model state

Comment: I have the state to monitor when the menu is open or closed. That is what is used when the state is toggled. When clicked, it fires `onFocus` which sets the state to `Open` and then fires `onClick` which toggles the state and thus sets it to `Closed`

Comment: ok, now I see the problem. Just my 2 cents to it... maybe you could modify your status and have also a `JustOpened` option. On the `onFocus` event you put the model in the `JustOpened` state and fire another event that after a certain number of milliseconds (probably using the `Time.delay` function) moves the status to `Open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend removing the `Toggle` action. It isn't necessary and only causes confusion because it disregards the current state.

Instead, you've probably got something already in your model that tracks whether the div is currently open, because I imagine you're styling differently based upon that fact. For this example, I'll assume your model looks something like this:

```elm
type alias Model =
  { open : Bool }
```

You can then remove the `Toggle` action and change the `onClick` handler to either send an `Open` or `Close` action based on the current state.

```elm
div
  [ onClick address (if model.open then Close else Open)
  , onFocus address Open
  , onBlur address Close
  ]
  [ ... some items with click handlers ]
```

This leaves you with the potential of firing two `Open` actions in a row, but that *should* be ok, since the second `Open` would in essence be a no-op and wouldn't change the already-open model at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did not implement your suggestion correctly because I'm getting the same thing. On click, the actions executed are `Open` and `Close`. I'm ok with two `Open` in a row but that does not seem to be happening

Comment: On the inner click, `mousedown` will fire prior to the parent `blur` event. If you created an action called `DelayClose` that sets a flag in your model on `mousedown` on the child element, then on the `Close` handler in `update`, you could check that flag, and then you could clear the flag in the inner click updates. If that doesn't work, could you provide more code to give a minimal working example of your problem?

Comment: Got it to work somehow by using the code above but delaying execution as suggested. `focus` calls `Open` after 250 ms and `blur` calls `Close` after 200 ms. It works about 90% of the time. Might have to tweak the time a bit though.